# html email => how can I set a background color for blocked images (MSO)?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I am looking for a working solution to style the placeholder of a blocked image in an html email.
I just need to have a colored background (green) and (white) text for example.

Currently I tried it like this:

```
<img src="https://my.isp.com/mailing/logo_mycompany.png" border="0" alt="Logo My Company" width="125" height="50" style="width:125px; height:50px; background-color:#004B4F; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 28px; color: #ffffff; display:block;" />
```

But no success, neither in Outlook nor in GMail or GMX. I am never getting a colored placeholder for the blocked image.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use a container div with `width:125px; height:50px; background-color:#004B4F;` the image must have `width:100%; height:100%;`

If you don't have any image you can see the background of the div.

Comment: That's a good overall start, the background color is green now. BUT the text is still grey, altough I've set color to white for the containing div and the img

Comment: Text from the alt attribute?

Comment: sorry, didn't get what you mean? I can see the alt text, but it's not being styled to white color, but still (default) grey

Answer (score 0):

You need to give color to the background in the table holding the image.

```
<td style="background-color: #004B4F;">
  <img src="https://my.isp.com/mailing/logo_mycompany.png" border="0" alt="Logo My Company" width="125" height="50" style="width:125px; height:50px; background-color:#004B4F; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 28px; color: #ffffff; display:block;" />
</td>
```

Then style the `ALT` tag as needed.

Comment: The table cell is larger than the image, so it would fill more space than needed

Comment: @JonSnow Make the table cell fit the image. Create a table just for the image. You'll get the effect you are looking for if an image fails to load.

Comment: First the placeholder look good. But I always have a thin colored border left below the image as soon as I load them.
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="auto" style="background-color:green"  etc etc>
<tr>
<td><img src="..."></td>
</tr>
</table>